# What is the best Scheme implementation for (sys-admin) shell scripts?

Tags: shell, scheme

I've gone through the academic Scheme stuff (read SICP, The Little Schemer, The Seasoned Schemer, TSPL) and been playing with Scheme as a toy for a while.

But I want to get practical.
Today I needed to write a shell script to do some batch file processing, and thought "why not do it in Scheme?". I did, and it was a joy.

Now I'm forced to wonder what the best implementation is for shell script type stuff.
I know all implementations differ in terms of what they implement beyond R5RS. (Basically, they differ in all the useful and practical extensions you'd want in a scripting language).

So I'd like to pick one implementation and stick to it. I'm looking for something that:

1. Is cross platform (Linux, OS X, Windows).
2. Has extensions that are useful in day-to-day shell scripting, and those extensions are part of the base install.
3. Is easy to install. (e.g. there are a number of pre-built binaries, and/or it is a standard package on many distros.)
4. Is actively developed, with an active community.
5. Has Unicode support.

I've been using Gambit so far. It seems to satisfy the above constraints. PLT seems like overkill. Wondering about Guile, MIT/GNU, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I've modified the title of my question. I wasn't clear that I intended to do sys-admin type stuff with Scheme. The problem is that a Scheme environment is something you can't expect to find on most machines. When I ssh into a box without a Scheme environment, I'd rather not have to install a 40MB download that includes an IDE, documentation, several language variations, sample apps, etc, in order to run a few small scripts. Another poster has informed me that I can install just the MzScheme runtime. This sounds like a better choice for me.

Comment: FWIW, you can even "compile" some code into an executable, which is basically a copy of your own executable with the bytecode appended at the end.  So as long as you have machines with the same libraries, etc, something like that could work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PLT Scheme](http://www.plt-scheme.org/) meets all of your criteria. Since it looks like you know that already, you should to use the [MzScheme](http://www.plt-scheme.org/software/mzscheme/) package. MzScheme is the runtime on top of which all of PLT is built.

If you were to download the full PLT Scheme install it would seem large as it includes a lot of documentation and an IDE in addition to the runtime.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually wondering about something like that but a link to that seems hard to find on the PLT website. In fact, knowing that it's there hasn't made it any clearer how one would find that on the PLT website if they didn't know about it.

Comment: It appears that the equivalent to the MzScheme package is now “Racket Textual”.

Answer (score 4):

Have you heard of [scsh](http://www.scsh.net/)? I haven't used it, but it sounds a lot like what you want.

Comment: Hmm... just took a look. 

"The latest version of scsh is 0.6.7, released May 16, 2006:"

Maybe it's perfect and doesn't need an update?

Comment: This is always the case with Scheme. :)

Comment: @Nathan Tell that to the R6RS committee.

Comment: I would, but I refuse to acknowledge that R6RS exists. :P

Comment: @z5h it still works well. It does need a few improvements maybe, but for the most part it does work well.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Gauche](http://practical-scheme.net/gauche/), which is:

1. Running on Linux, OS X, Windows w/
   Cygwin and some other [UNIX-like
   platforms](http://practical-scheme.net/gauche/features.html#ports),
2. The base install contains
   POSIX-compliant system libraries and
   useful modules such as
   network protocols, file system, 
   DBM, multithreading, etc...
3. Several package system such as MacPorts, apt-get, yum are available
   (or just say `configure`, `make` and
   `make install`),
4. There are active English and Japanese mailing list,
5. Supports UTF-8 as an internal encoding.